# Запуск с правами администратора

Tags: c#

Вводные данные:
VS2017 запущенный от имени Администратора
.NET Framework 4.6.1
Язык: C#

Делаю проект, в котором необходимо запустить командную строку от имени администратора, т.к. нужно отключить (а потом включить отдельное правило).
Поискал и почитал возможные способы и все сводилось к тому, что во вкладке **проект>безопасность** нужно поставить галочку возле **"Включить параметры безопасности ClickOnce-приложений"**. Я это сделал, пробовал ставить и **"Это приложение с полным доверием"**, и **"Это приложение с частичным доверием">"Зона из которой будет установлено:" - "другой"**. НО все сводилось к тому, что при выставлении в строке манифеста:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
\\или
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
```

После начала компиляции выдает ошибку:
**ClickOnce не поддерживает уровень выполнения запроса "requireAdministrator"** или **"highestAvailable"** во втором случае.
На **"asInvoker"** не жалуется, но и программа не работает.

От вас прошу помощи либо как сделать так, чтобы CMD запускалась от имени Администратора, либо программа изначально запускалась как администратор.

Comment: Как вы это добавляли, куда добавляли, выбран ли нужный манифест по умолчанию?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ну добавил через вкладку **Проект>Свойства>Безопасность**
Без понятия, стоит он по умолчанию или нет, использовал справку от майкрософтов, там ничего про это не было сказано

Comment: А снять галку с "Включить параметры безопасности ClickOnce-приложений" пробовали?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ щас попробовал, ошибку не выдает, но и правило не изменяет. 1 раз, до того как вопрос еще поставил, чет делал, VS выдал ошибку, но при этом все скомпилировалось и при нажатии на кнопку(WinForm) правило менялось (Проверял раз 10 наверно), но после того, как код уже дописал, перестало работать(изменять правило)

Comment: Ну тогда проблема наверно в "дописанном" коде, нет? Если вы сняли  "Включить параметры безопасности ClickOnce-приложений" и поставили в манифесте правило для запуска администратором, то ваше приложение уже как минимум должно было собраться и запуститься от администратора. Как вы запускаете "cmd", с какими правами, с какими параметрами - вы нам не показываете, так что вы тогда от нас ожидаете услышать?)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да, я щас протестил без "дописанного" кода и проблема оказалась в нем (он правило отключает, а включает до того, как нужно). 
Но все равно спасибо, тк с галочкой все равно не работало). Без галочки все ок.

Answer (score 1):

Снять галку с **"Включить параметры безопасности ClickOnce-приложений"**
При этом, можно будет увидеть, что сам *.exe будет запускаться от имени администратора.